# EF Core 7 Json column projections - LINQKit - LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, linqkit, ef-core-7.0

I have an issue with mapping an EF Core 7 Json column into an class. I am presented with the following exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'JsonQueryExpression(p.Addresses, $.AddressList)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

The code below is the projection that is mapping the queried `AddressesData` class to the `Addresses` class.  (Which the `Addresses` is an EF Core 7 Json column, see DBContext at the bottom)

```cs
public static class AddressesDataExpressions
{
    public static class Projections
    {
        private static Expression<Func<AddressesData, Addresses>> Projection()
        {
            return a => new()
            {
                AllAddresses = a.AddressList.AsQueryable().AsEnumerable().Select(ad => new Address
                {
                    City = ad.City,
                    CountryCode = ad.CountryCode,
                    FirstLine = ad.FirstLine,
                    PostCode = ad.PostCode,
                    SecondLine = ad.SecondLine
                }).ToList(),
                PrimaryAddressIndex = a.Primary
            };
        }
        private static Func<AddressesData, Addresses>? _project;
        [Expandable(nameof(Projection))]
        public static Addresses Project(AddressesData data)
        {
            _project ??= Projection().Compile();

            return _project(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the method that contains the EF Query

```cs
public async Task<CustomerSettings?> GetSettingsAsync(int customerId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var customerSettings = await _appDbContext.Customers
        .Where(c => c.ResourceId == customerId)
        .Select(c => new CustomerSettings
        {
            Addresses = ADE.Projections.Project(c.Addresses),
            Privacy = CPE.Projections.Project(c.Privacy),
            SocialMedia = new()
            {
                Facebook = c.SocialMedia.Facebook,
                Instragam = c.SocialMedia.Instragam,
                Twitter = c.SocialMedia.Twitter
            }
        })
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

    return customerSettings;
}
```

However, as you can see in the above code, I'm also using a projection for `Privacy` which I've converted back to an original Relational Database format with a table instead of Json column to test this issue, and this works without any issues.

I was just wondering if there's currently no support for EF Core 7 Json columns?

Below is the `AddressesData` database model class & the `Addresses` it is being mapped into.

```cs
public class AddressesData
{
    public int? Primary { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AddressData> AddressList { get; set; } = new List<AddressData>();
}
```

```cs
public class Addresses
{
    public Addresses()
    {
        AllAddresses = new List<Address>();
    }
    public Addresses(IEnumerable<Address> addresses)
    {
        AllAddresses = new List<Address>();
        AllAddresses.AddRange(addresses);
    }

    public int? PrimaryAddressIndex { get; set; }
    public List<Address> AllAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the EF Db context config too

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ResourceData> Resources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DepartmentData> Departments { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<PersonData> People { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<StaffMemberData> StaffMembers { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<CustomerData> Customers { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<CustomerPrivacyData> CustomerPrivacyData { get; set; } = null!;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DepartmentData>().OwnsOne(p => p.Address, options => options.ToJson());

        // Have to use TPH if we're using a base class with JSON columns, TPC is not currently supported
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonData>().OwnsOne(p => p.SocialMedia, options => options.ToJson());
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonData>().OwnsOne(p => p.Addresses, builder =>
        {
            builder.ToJson();
            builder.OwnsMany(a => a.AddressList);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<StaffMemberData>().OwnsMany(p => p.Certifications, options => options.ToJson());
        modelBuilder.Entity<StaffMemberData>().OwnsMany(p => p.Titles, options => options.ToJson());

        //modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerData>().OwnsOne(p => p.Privacy, options => options.ToJson());
    }
}
```

I still receive the same error after removing `.AsQueryable().AsEnumberable()` from the projection and also removing just `.AsEnumerable()`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Expandable` looks good, for sure without `.AsQueryable().AsEnumberable()`. Have you tried it without LINQKit? Maybe it is EF Core limitation?

Comment: Does indeed look like it's an issue with EF Core itself, rather than LINQKit. Can't seem to project an ICollection stored in a JSON column.

Comment: It appears this is a limitation with EF Core 7 and not an issue specific to LINQKit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76374551/how-do-i-project-a-collection-inside-a-json-column-with-ef-core-7