# How do I project a collection inside a JSON column with EF Core 7?

Tags: entity-framework-core

- EF Core version: 7.0.4
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer (SQL Server 2019)
- Target framework: .NET 7.0

Given the following models, I am unable to project the `AddressesData.AddressList` property when it is stored as a JSON column.

```c#
public class AddressData
{
    public string FirstLine { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? SecondLine { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; } = null!;
    public string PostCode { get; set; } = null!;
    public string CountryCode { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```c#
public class AddressesData
{
    public int? Primary { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AddressData> AddressList { get; set; } = new List<AddressData>();
}
```

```c#
public class CustomerData
{
    public AddressesData Addresses { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Fluent Configuration

```c#
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerData>().OwnsOne(c => c.Addresses, builder =>
    {
        builder.ToJson();
        builder.OwnsMany(a => a.AddressList);
    });
}
```

When I try to use the following projection I get an exception from EF Core, seems it's unable to translate the projection for the collection in the JSON column.

```c#
var customerSettings = await _appDbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Id == customerId)
    .Select(c => new
    {
        PrimaryAddress = c.Addresses.Primary,
        AllAddresses = c.Addresses.AddressList.Select(a => new
        {
           a.City,
           a.CountryCode,
           a.FirstLine,
           a.PostCode,
           a.SecondLine
        })
    })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'JsonQueryExpression(p.Addresses, $.AddressList)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I can project the `AddressList` into a property, but obviously this isn't converting the data inside it to a different type.

```c#
var customerSettings = await _appDbContext.Customers
    .Where(c => c.Id == customerId)
    .Select(c => new
    {
        PrimaryAddress = c.Addresses.Primary,
        AllAddresses = c.Addresses.AddressList
    })
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Ideally I'm trying to keep the projections agnostic of the EF Core configuration. The `Addresses` and `AddressList` properties could be configured to have their own relational tables.

Comment: Which database and version are you using? JSON column mapping actually tries to map the query to server-side operations, not load the entire JSON and parse it. The error shows that the JSON query was recognized (which is why JsonQueryExpression is used) but the database provider can't can't generate the equivalent SQL

Comment: The [JSON Columns docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#json-columns) explain that Microsoft provides support for JSON in SQL Server, which offers JSON functions since SQL Server 2016. For PostgreSQL or MySQL JSON mapping is offered by the provider authors. Notice that for MySQL the docs mention the open source Pomelo provider, not Oracle's provider

Comment: I've updated the description with the platform details. This is being run against SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Understand that the query gets translated to SQL. When you project just the `AddressList` property, the column returned contains the raw JSON array (no casting in SQL). Then, I assume, EF Core is deserialising that JSON to the model. My hope is/was that the `.Select` on that would happen client side, but that I could keep it within the same projection code.

Comment: There wouldn't be much point to wholesale JSON deserialization. You could deserialize the object yourself in that case, eg in a helper property. Useful, but not something needed in the ORM itself. JSON column support means the ORM is trying to actually use the server's JSON features.  The query's problem is that it's trying to flatten a nested array of objects. This [isn't possible with the current JSON Path expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I suspect what you want is coming in EF Core 8. To query the array you'd need `OPENJSON`. In the EF Core Github repo unit tests with OPENJSON appeared just last month, [as this unit test shows](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/c0f9164797cdf79db43145c6df3af9fef754c4f1/test/EFCore.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/Query/ComplexNavigationsCollectionsSharedTypeQuerySqlServerTest.cs).

Comment: Check [What's new in EF Core 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew) too, which describes the new JSON functionality, including array access or querying collections

Comment: Already checking out EF Core 8 , although I don't think `OPENJSON` will resolve the issue. For me, this is about parity in how projections work between using JSON columns for the data and relational tables. I could reconfigure the list of addresses to be a reference collection pointing to another table. The projection would work fine, but unfortunately use a `LEFT JOIN` and wouldn't be as performant.

Comment: There's no promise of parity. Handling collections is starting to come in EF Core 8. To query a JSON field as a table you *need* OPENJSON, so that's what you need to search for, either in Github or the docs.

Comment: Finally, without JSON indexing, the query will always have to crunch the entire JSON string so you can't talk about parity, at least in SQL Server. Other databases like PostgreSQL have far better support, including explicit JSON types (even binary ones, jsonb), indexes and operators. In SQL Server we'll keep having problems. *Maybe* you can work around the problem using `FromSqlRaw` and `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(..)` to expand the JSON collection into a table.